# displaying current minute of a soccer match

Tags: asp-classic

I could not figure out the logic I would need to display a current minute of a soccer match. I have three fields in the database.

DateFirstStarted
DateSecondStarted
DateFullEnded

I should enter DateFirstStarted when the game starts and on the website. i.e. game starts at 7:05pm, on 7:25pm it should display '20 on the website. However, it should stop on the 45th minute. Then, I enter DateSecondStarted when the second half starts and should count from 46 to 90 and freeze there. Do I make sense? How can I do it? Is there a better way to do this?

---

Something not too complicated should do it. I will update start date of first half and start date of second half myself.

Here is how I tried it. I dont get an error but its not working. Any suggestion appreciated.

```
DateFirstStarted    =   objLiveCommentary("DateFirstStarted")
DateFirstEnded      =   DateAdd("n", 45, DateFirstStarted)
DateSecondStarted   =   objLiveCommentary("DateSecondStarted")
DateSecondEnded     =   DateAdd("n", 45, DateSecondStarted)

If      DateFirstStarted    =>  NOW()   =>  DateFirstEnded  Then
Response.Write "first half"
ElseIf  DateSecondStarted   =>  NOW()   =>  DateSecondEnded Then
Response.Write "second half"
End If
```

Comment: You need to account for extra times. 2nd minute of extra time in first half is *not* the 46th minute of the match, is the 45th minute and 2 extra time minutes. The 46th minute is the 1st minute of the second half. And also the match can be suspended and the clock stopped. Storing only start time and end time is not going to be enough.

Comment: I agree with Remus 100%. If you are doing something as in-depth and accurate as ESPN for example, you need access to some sort of a live feed telling you when game is actively being played or not. That is, it should tell you about TimeOuts and when the game is paused for Referee calls, medical emergencies, etc. HOWEVER, if you are going for something super simplistic, yes, your logic sounds just fine. You can look into using the Classic ASP Timer to help implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DateDiff function?

You pass it two datetimes and it will give you the total amount of mins / seconds / hours etc between the two values.

http://www.w3schools.com/vbScript/func_datediff.asp

E.g.

```
If DateDiff("n",StartOfMatch,Now()) < 45 Then
   FirstHalf = True
Elseif DateDiff("n",StartOfMatch,Now()) >= 45 Then
   SecondHalf = True
Else
   MatchEnded = True
End If
```

Hope this helps you?

C